# HTML&CSS é possível desabilitar o scrollbar direito de uma pagina html?

Tags: html, css

Minha pagina html esta com muitos objetos, mas quero deixar todos eles de forma q nao precise aparecer o scrollbar, é possível desabilitar o scrollbar?

Comment: Queres somente que o scrollbar desapareça  ou queres que a página faça zoom para não precisa de scrollbar?

Comment: Você tem este exemplo em CSS? Onde eu coloco este comando?

Comment: É isto que queres? https://jsfiddle.net/9smm6L8z/

Comment: Isto mesmo @Sergio! Obrigado a todos! Assim q a resposta for colocada vou dar como encerrado!

Comment: @renan quando não tenho a certeza pergunto primeiro :P Mas ás vezes perco a chance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar `overflow: hidden` para esconder a(s) barra(s) de scroll.

Tendo em conta que se deve mudar só o necessário neste caso podes usar somente `overflow-y` (somente eixo vertical) para ser mais específico. Aplicando isso ao documento seria

```
html {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/9smm6L8z/

<sub>Se quiseres usar força bruta (e em casos raros é necessário) podes usar isso aplicado a todos os elementos como o [@William Novak referiu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/137890/htmlcss-%C3%A9-poss%C3%ADvel-desabilitar-o-scrollbar-direito-de-uma-pagina-html?noredirect=1#comment285907_137890). Mas a evitar, excepto casos raros uma vez por vida de programador :)</sub>